# Dataframe creating columns with rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Restructure the df using col values and missing values should be  replaced with 0.

my df :

```
a     b                 c       

0     AM                24
1     AM                20
4     AM                3
6     AM                2
0     AY                13
1     AY                16
2     AY                1
4     AY                5
6     AY                2
```

Desired df:

```
b     0    1   2  4   6 

AM    24   20  0  3   2 
Ay    13   16  1  5   2
```

Thanks!!